# Mongoose model on MongoDB collection fetching no data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB version 3.4.7, Mongoose 4.11.13 driver for creating Model on MongoDB collection and creating AggregationCursor to process each document individually to populate some JS variables. But it seems the Mongoose model is not bringing any data into the cursor from MongoDB collection. 
I tried aggregate operation with `mongodb` driver previously but it doesn't work 
[**(check here)**](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3160) and opted for `mongoose` instead. But it seems there is some problem here as well or I am missing anything here? Updated my AggregationCursor for better understanding. Any quick help will be greatly appreciated.

Node version 3.10.10, ExpressJS 3.2.6

My Node.JS code is as follows:

```
app.get('/reviews',function(req,res)
{
    res.render("chart");
    var obj = {};
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var assert = require('assert');
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        seller_id: String,
        product_id: String,
        product_desc: String,
        reviews: {
            total_review_count: Number,
            five_star_count: Number,
            four_star_count: Number,
            three_star_count: Number,
            two_star_count: Number,
            one_star_count: Number
        }
    }); 

    //specify the name of MongoDB collection as third argument of model
    var ProductReview = mongoose.model('ProductReview', schema, 'product_reviews'); //<-- here

    //review count placeholders
     var totalReviewCounts = [], FiveStarCounts = [], FourStarCounts = [], ThreeStarCounts = [],
        TwoStarCounts = [], OneStarCounts = []; 

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sellerrank', function() {
        var cursor = ProductReview.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                        seller_id: { $exists: true, $nin: [null] }
                }
            }
        ])
                .allowDiskUse(true)
                .group({    _id: { seller_id: '$seller_id'}, 
                            total_review_count: {
                                $sum: {
                                    $cond : [ 
                                        { $eq : ["$reviews.total_review_count", null] },
                                        0,
                                        "$reviews.total_review_count"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            five_star_count: {
                                $sum: {
                                    $cond : [ 
                                        { $eq : ["$reviews.five_star_count", null] },
                                        0,
                                        "$reviews.five_star_count"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            four_star_count: {
                                $sum: {
                                    $cond : [ 
                                        { $eq : ["$reviews.four_star_count", null] },
                                        0,
                                        "$reviews.four_star_count"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            three_star_count: {
                                $sum: {
                                    $cond : [ 
                                        { $eq : ["$reviews.three_star_count", null] },
                                        0,
                                        "$reviews.three_star_count"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            two_star_count: {
                                $sum: {
                                    $cond : [ 
                                        { $eq : ["$reviews.two_star_count", null] },
                                        0,
                                        "$reviews.two_star_count"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            one_star_count: {
                                $sum: {
                                    $cond : [ 
                                        { $eq : ["$reviews.one_star_count", null] },
                                        0,
                                        "$reviews.one_star_count"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                    })
                .cursor({ batchSize: 100})
                .exec();
        console.log(cursor); **//<-- printing the cursor here**
cursor.each(function(err,doc){
            assert.equal(null,err);
            console.log(doc);
            if(doc!=null){
                var seller_id = doc['_id'];
                 var totalReviews = doc['total_review_count'];
                  var fiveStarReviews = doc['five_star_count'];
                  var fourStarReviews = doc['four_star_count'];
                  var threeStarReviews = doc['three_star_count'];
                  var twoStarReviews = doc['two_star_count'];
                  var oneStarReviews = doc['one_star_count'];

                  totalReviewCounts.push({"value" : totalReviews});
                  FiveStarCounts.push({"value" : fiveStarReviews});
                  FourStarCounts.push({"value" : fourStarReviews});
                  ThreeStarCounts.push({"value" : threeStarReviews});
                  TwoStarCounts.push({"value" : twoStarReviews});
                  OneStarCounts.push({"value" : oneStarReviews});
            } 
        });
    });
 var dataset = [
      {
        "seriesname" : "Total positive reviews",
        "data" : totalReviewCounts
      },
      {
        "seriesname" : "5 star reviews",
        "data": FiveStarCounts
      },
      {
        "seriesname" : "4 star reviews",
        "data" : FourStarCounts
      },
      {
        "seriesname" : "3 star reviews",
        "data": ThreeStarCounts
      },
      {
        "seriesname" : "2 star reviews",
        "data" : TwoStarCounts
      },
      {
        "seriesname" : "1 star reviews",
        "data": OneStarCounts
      }
    ];
    console.log(dataset); //<-- **dataset is printed here**

    var response = {
              "dataset" : dataset
            };

    obj['dataset'] = dataset;
    console.log(obj);
    res.send(obj);
    mongoose.disconnect();  
});
```

When I am running the above Node.JS Express code, I am getting the output of `console.log(dataset)` as

```
[ { seriesname: 'Total positive reviews', data: [] },
  { seriesname: '5 star reviews', data: [] },
  { seriesname: '4 star reviews', data: [] },
  { seriesname: '3 star reviews', data: [] },
  { seriesname: '2 star reviews', data: [] },
  { seriesname: '1 star reviews', data: [] } ]
```

**There is data in my local MongoDB collection 'product_reviews' but there is no data fetched into the cursor.**

My Aggregation cursor as shown in `console.log(cursor)` is as follows:

```
AggregationCursor {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   Store {
     s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: BSON {},
  ns: 'sellerrank.product_reviews',
  cmd: 
   { aggregate: 'product_reviews',
     pipeline: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     allowDiskUse: true,
     cursor: { batchSize: 100 } },
  options: 
   { allowDiskUse: true,
     cursor: { batchSize: 100 },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     cursorFactory: { [Function: AggregationCursor] super_: [Object], define: [Object], INIT: 0, OPEN: 1, CLOSED: 2 },
     disconnectHandler: Store { s: [Object], length: [Getter] } },
  topology: 
   Server {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { reconnect: [Function: reconnectHandler],
        reconnectFailed: [Function: reconnectFailedHandler],
        serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function],
        serverOpening: [Function],
        serverClosed: [Function],
        topologyOpening: [Function],
        topologyClosed: [Function],
        topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        attemptReconnect: [Function],
        monitoring: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Function],
        destroy: [Function: destroyHandler] },
     _eventsCount: 17,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     id: 0,
     s: 
      { options: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        Cursor: [Object],
        bson: BSON {},
        pool: [Object],
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        monitoring: true,
        inTopology: false,
        monitoringInterval: 5000,
        topologyId: -1,
        serverDescription: [Object],
        topologyDescription: [Object] },
     ismaster: 
      { ismaster: true,
        maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
        maxWriteBatchSize: 1000,
        localTime: 2017-10-02T14:21:27.032Z,
        maxWireVersion: 5,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        readOnly: false,
        ok: 1 },
     lastIsMasterMS: 12,
     monitoringProcessId: 
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 5621,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null },
     initalConnect: false,
     wireProtocolHandler: WireProtocol { legacyWireProtocol: WireProtocol {} },
     _type: 'server',
     clientInfo: 
      { driver: [Object],
        os: [Object],
        platform: 'Node.js v6.11.3, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.15' },
     lastUpdateTime: 0,
     lastWriteDate: 0,
     staleness: 0 },
  cursorState: 
   { cursorId: null,
     cmd: 
      { aggregate: 'product_reviews',
        pipeline: [Object],
        allowDiskUse: true,
        cursor: [Object] },
     documents: [],
     cursorIndex: 0,
     dead: false,
     killed: false,
     init: false,
     notified: false,
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     batchSize: 100,
     currentLimit: 0,
     transforms: undefined },
  logger: Logger { className: 'Cursor' },
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: true,
     highWaterMark: 16,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: 
   { maxTimeMS: null,
     state: 0,
     streamOptions: {},
     bson: BSON {},
     ns: 'sellerrank.product_reviews',
     cmd: 
      { aggregate: 'product_reviews',
        pipeline: [Object],
        allowDiskUse: true,
        cursor: [Object] },
     options: 
      { allowDiskUse: true,
        cursor: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        disconnectHandler: [Object] },
     topology: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 17,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        id: 0,
        s: [Object],
        ismaster: [Object],
        lastIsMasterMS: 12,
        monitoringProcessId: [Object],
        initalConnect: false,
        wireProtocolHandler: [Object],
        _type: 'server',
        clientInfo: [Object],
        lastUpdateTime: 0,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        staleness: 0 },
     topologyOptions: 
      { host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        socketOptions: {},
        auto_reconnect: true,
        clientInfo: [Object],
        forceServerObjectId: false,
        w: 1,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        bson: BSON {} },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] },
  sortValue: undefined,
  eachAsync: [Function] }
```