# Iterate over MongoDB collection aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB version 3.4.7, Node version 3.10.10, ExpressJS 3.2.6

I am trying to create AggregationCursor and then iterate over each document individually to populate some JS variables. I tried adopting a similar approach as answered in [Iterate over Mongodb cursor from aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577895/iterate-over-mongodb-cursor-from-aggregate)

My code can be seen at [Mongoose model on MongoDB collection fetching no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528595/mongoose-model-on-mongodb-collection-fetching-no-data)

I initially tried with mongodb driver but it doesn't work [**(check the link here)**](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3160) and opted for mongoose instead.

But Mongoose model seems to not fetching data from MongoDB collection.

Since it is such a basic aggregation requirement (doing some aggregation and then iterate over aggregation cursor to process each document at a time), I am wondering what may be the best practice to achieve such scenario?

Look forward to suggestions with insightful code snippets